# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable for date function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I implemented Kryo serialization in spark 1.6.2 in scala. I got `"org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable"` for below getdate method.

I am using below getdate function in map transformation to get date.

```
def getdate(s: String,format_ts:String): Option[Date] = s match {
case "" => null
case _ =>
  val format = new SimpleDateFormat(format_ts)

  Try(new Date(format.parse(s).getTime)).toOption


 }
```

But when I insert null inplace of date column, it is working fine.

Can someone help me what are the classes need to be part of kryo serialization?.Thanks

Comment: Option and Date both need to be serializable. As an aside, why return `null` from the first case rather than `None`?

Comment: thanks Dave. I changed it None. Can u please let me know how to serialize option as a part of kyro

Comment: I don't have first hand experience with Kryo. I think you might need an additional library that has the code to serialize the "basic" Scala classes, such as Option. Chill is a library with this goal: https://github.com/twitter/chill#chill-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much familiar with Kryo serialization in spark. But according to my experiance SimpleDateFormat is not serializable with spark.
SimpleDateFormat class Implemented Serializable in java. But it is not serializable when using with spark( When it parse to the Executor program of hadoop, the class can't be serialized.) I got the same error.
You can use **LocalDate** instead of using SimpleDateFormat for your task. For me LocalDate worked fine in many cases.